# how to get all the paragraphs of an article in an array using regex and PHP?

Tags: php, regex

Please help me to get all the paragraphs from an article in an array. The paragraph contains no html. I just need to separate the paragraph through line breaks. Note an article may have multi line breaks.

Comment: There sure are a lot of "please write me a regex" 'questions' on Stack Overflow...

Comment: have you got an example?

Comment: Can you give an example? How is a paragraph distinguished form another one? Without sample data it is impossible to help and just guessing.

Comment: Define "paragraphs". Please show a live example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small program that detects line breaks & puts in an array :

```
<?php 

$text = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and 




typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys s
tandard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it 
to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic 
typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
 sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus 
 PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.';
$splitted_para_arr = preg_split("/[\n]+/",$text);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($splitted_para_arr);
echo '</pre>';
 ?>
```

Comment: yes , there are tons of variations , you can eaven explode("\n",$article); , however if you have mutiple lines breaks at once for example "some text\n\n\n some more text" you're code will return an array containing more than just 2 values .

Comment: $paragraph = nl2br($paragraph); $explode=explode('<br />',$paragraph); And now $explode contains all your paragraphs

Comment: @user547188 we can not explode a string through `<br/>`

Comment: are you sure? because i have tested and its running? don't know whether will it be an issue if i transfer my files to another server?

Answer (score 0):

```
$article = 'line1
line2

line3



line4 line4 line4

line10
';
//replace multiple linebreaks 
//( trim it too and add a new line at the beginig of the string )
$article = "\n" . preg_replace('/\n{2,}/', "\n", trim($article));
var_dump($article);
//match all lines
preg_match_all('/\n(.*)/', $article, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this

```
$para="This is line one!

This is another line.";

$x=explode("\n",$para); 
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($x); 
now use array_filter() for the string length >1
```